# Uniqueness of Competitive Equilibrium Conditions

Tags: preferences, competitive-equilibrium

I know that if a consumer has strictly convex preferences it may not guarantee uniqueness of CE. 
I believe that we need monotonicity of preferences as well but would like to hear any thoughts of this claim or whether any other conditions may be needed.

Thanks